# Styling a button within a certain form

Tags: html, css

Very quick and basic question but one I can't seem to find the answer to online.

In CSS, is it possible to style a "submit" based purely on the form it is in? Furthermore is there any reason to not do this, and instead to use an specific name like #subit_search_form

Comment: How do you uniquely identify your `form`? Its position in the DOM/HTML, or by an `id`, by class-name(s)..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is. Lets say your form has an id of `MyForm`, your CSS would look like this:

```
#MyForm button
{
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayfxm/)

this will style all `button` elements with the form with id `MyForm`.

Comment: What about submit boxes like this:   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />

Comment: well, you could use the id of the input: `#MyForm #submit { }`. But if you have an ID (which should be unique) then you may aswell just use that ID directly, like so: `#submit { }`. I would recommend using classes though

Comment: Right, ok I understand now

Answer (score 2):

depends on what hooks you have to style...
give the form an id and then...

```
<form id="certain-form" >
    ...
    <button type="submit">Your Button</button>
</form>
```

The css:

```
#certain-form button { ..your unique styles.. }
```

Comment: What about submit boxes like this: <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />

Comment: same thing just replace button with input[type="submit"] OR css: #certain-form input#submit. best to not use submit as id/name on a button or input as it plays up with some js from what I remember...

Comment: @Jimmy: if you know the `id` of the button (which ***must be unique within the document***) then simply use the `id` to select the `button`. If there's a chance that `button` might, via script, be moved elsewhere in the document then select by its ancestor `form` element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible. 
Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kX3Wp/).

**The HTML:**

```
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="button" value="Button" class="button"></input>
    </label>
</form>
```

**OR**

```
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="submit" value="Button" class="button"></input>
    </label>
</form>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.button
{
    border-top:     2px solid #a3ceda;
    border-left:        2px solid #a3ceda;
    border-right:       2px solid #4f6267;
    border-bottom:      2px solid #4f6267;
    padding:        10px 20px !important;
    font-size:      14px !important;
    background-color:   #c4f1fe;
    font-weight:        bold;
    color:          #2d525d;
}
```

Hope this Helps.

**EDIT**

If you want to target using specific attribute. Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kX3Wp/1/).

**The CSS Change**

```
input[type="submit"]
{
    border-top:     2px solid #a3ceda;
    border-left:        2px solid #a3ceda;
    border-right:       2px solid #4f6267;
    border-bottom:      2px solid #4f6267;
    padding:        10px 20px !important;
    font-size:      14px !important;
    background-color:   #c4f1fe;
    font-weight:        bold;
    color:          #2d525d;
}
```

Alternatively this also can be used.

Comment: This does not limit it to a specific form. unless you only use the 'button' class within that one form. But then that's still not specific to a form, rather to a class

Comment: I voted you up, but this doesnt style based on a specific form

Comment: here is my updated solution. http://jsfiddle.net/kX3Wp/1/
This is purely based on input[type]. I have updated the EDIT in my answer. - @Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share, although your problem have been resolved..

If you want to add style to `submit` instead to use specific name of form like `#subit_search_form`, You could use jquery selector `form` with `name` and `input` with `type` to add css style.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("form[name=subit_search_form] input[type=submit]").css({
    "background-color": "#FE9900",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "font-family": "Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
    "border": "1px solid #000066",
    "cursor": "pointer"
});
</script>

<form name="subit_search_form">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

<kbd>**[jsffile](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/5xWBy/1/)**</kbd>

But I prefer with solution from @musefan, using `button`